# Using RUN command in Dockerfile on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, bash, docker, docker-compose

In my Dockerfile I have

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
COPY devops/scripts/setup.sh .
RUN ls
RUN chmod +x ./setup.sh 
RUN ./setup.sh
WORKDIR /app
```

Step 3 I am using just to show that file is actually present.

When used in docker-compose this works perfectly on **Linux**, but when runnning `docker-compose up` on **Windows** it results in

```
> docker-compose up
Building create_template
Step 1/6 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
 ---> 511c1f563ce6
Step 2/6 : COPY devops/scripts/setup.sh .
 ---> 3d3bb4ab9bc4
Step 3/6 : RUN ls
 ---> Running in 43ad6e244ed8
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
setup.sh     <--- 
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
Removing intermediate container 43ad6e244ed8
 ---> aa32210d6a87
Step 4/6 : RUN chmod +x ./setup.sh
 ---> Running in 2d6858495355
Removing intermediate container 2d6858495355
 ---> 5e0388623851
Step 5/6 : RUN ./setup.sh
 ---> Running in abb3a52fe6ec
/bin/sh: 1: ./setup.sh: not found
ERROR: Service 'create_template' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./setup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Is there a way to use same dockerimage files and commands on both systems or do I have to have alternate dockerimage and docker-compose for each?
Thank you

Comment: What is the shebang line of your `setup.sh`? If it's using an interpreter that doesn't exist in the image (e.g. you're using `#! /bin/bash` and bash isn't in the image), you might get a `not found` error.

Comment: If your docker is running on windows 10 with WSL:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 you can run shell scripts. otherwise you can try cygwin. not very elegant but it can work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your example on windows & reproduce your problem.

The root cause is when you new the file `setup.sh` on windows, it's `DOS format`. You need to use git-bash or other similar to transfer the file format on host to `unix format` in advance before compose or build, something like:

```
dos2unix setup.sh
```

Another way is do it in `Dockerfile`, and this also compatible when you use linux host, something like next:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix setup.sh
RUN ./setup.sh
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the info, was it just about the (CR LF) vs (LF)?
That error message about not finding the file was very misleading

Comment: Yes, just CRLF issue.